# How to get rid of VBA security warning

Tags: ms-access, vba, warnings

I developed a Access application using VBA.  Everytime I open Access up, I get the following:

[image: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/wgn5B5PllVXGuG6W4_xiFa1rouSpDSn27MC0nzPkgJ5CPN8BKpAn-gDFsVS4GZtepY-c4jtbEupKeV227ogICQlzcg=s512]

I have to click *Options* -> *Enable Content* to run my macros. This application will be shared among a couple of people at work who are not so tech savvy.  So as per requirements, I must remove it. I've tried signing/packaging the database, but it still does not get rid of the warning.

Comment: From the looks of your screenshot it's Access 2007 and not 2003, or 2010.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To do that you have to add the location from where the Excel is launched in the "Trusted Locations".

To do this, do as follows:

- In Excel Options, go to Trust Center and then Trusted Locations
- Add the location.

This would have to be done on a per-pc basis.

In addition, there is no way to do this from an Excel file point of view as this would completely anihiliate the security feature of letting the user chose to run VBA code or not.

Also a little sidenote, if you sign your Excel file, you'd still need the recipient to trust you as a publisher, so that's why your solution probably did not work.

Edit:

Taking into comments, there does seem to be a way to do it programmatically. As taken from XpertsExchange,

Why not just set the registry entry from code, without invoking Shell? Use the cRegistry class found here:

http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Libraries/Registry_and_Ini_Files/Complete_Registry_Control/article.asp

VBA Code:

```
 Dim c As New cRegistry
    With c
        .ClassKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER
        .SectionKey = "Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\YourTrustedLocationName"
        .ValueKey = "Path"
        .ValueType = REG_DWORD
        .Value = "Full path to Trusted Folder"
    End With
```

The only caveat is that YourTrustedLocationname must be unique ...

You'd have to try if it should be .ValueType = REG_DWORD or REG_SZ. I'm not sure on that one.

Comment: thankyou. Is there any way to "embed" it in. I don't have the luxary to add a trusted location.

Comment: Yes mate. Otherwise you would defeat the purpose of the security feature as a whole. Imagine me doing this, packing a VBA virus and sending you the file. If the file would auto-execute macros without asking me first, there would be no sense at all of having this added security feature.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you wouldn't have the 'luxury' of adding a trusted location.  Of course you would.  It's a work function and if they want it to operate, they'll allow it.

Comment: Hey, Sorry what about when they enable it the first time, and then I can run some VBA code that puts it in the trusted location section?

Comment: Minor correction to your opening statement. It is Access not Excel being asked about ... as you rightly note further on when you list Access in the registry section key for trusted locations. This confirms that Excel and Access do not share trusted locations within the registry. For anyone considering this approach it is advisable not to choose a general location for the trusted folder (such as My Documents, which can be an easy default for downloads of ill repute).

Answer (score 8):

Though this question is years old, just in case it may help, here is what I did. It is a different approach to those already proposed, and it may serve someone else.
In my case, MsAccess was not opened directly by the user. Instead, MsAccess was started using automation from within another custom application. So, instead of having the user to click ‘Enable Content’, we had this custom application tell MsAccess to enable the macros. Something similar to this:

```
cli = create_object("Access.Application")
cli.AutomationSecurity = 1                # 1 = msoAutomationSecurityLow
cli.visible = true
cli.opencurrentdatabase("c:/Users/jmperez/AppData/Local/Temp/DB_TMP.mdb")
```

(sorry about the above code, it’s not from a ‘standard’ or ‘popular’ programming language, but it shouldn’t be difficult to adapt to Visual Basic or anything else)

Comment: This code is exactly what I wanted.  I've been searching for a way to open an access database file hidden using the application object for a long time.  Setting the `AutomationSecurity` property to 1 was the key to suppressing the trusted location warning dialog box.

Answer (score 3):

It's a per-user option.  Everyone would need to 'trust' your workbook.

In Excel, hit the menu button, and choose Excel Options.  In that window, pick Trust Center, and then Trust Center Settings.  In that window, choose Trusted Locations.

Once on that screen, you will probably want to check "Allow Trusted Locations on my network" and then click Add Location and add the network location of your workbook.

Answer (score 2):

Have your macro signed by a trusted authority.

Comment: Access 2007 does not allow code-signing in database files of types .accdb, .accdr and .accde. MS took the feature away (and brought it back in version 2010). Version 2007 will allow the signing of code in .mdb type databases, otherwise it will only allow signing of an install package (which is no good if the end-user is using Access runtime and has no easy access to adding a trusted location).

Answer (score 0):

What I did was creating a setup project with visual studio 2010 (under setup & deployment projects). Within this project you configure to install/copy the MS Access application to "C:\Ntapps\MsOffice\Office12\ACCWIZ\". This is a folder for trusted databases. Then create a shortcut to the MS Access application and install that one at the desired location.

When everything is ok and the install is complete, MS Access (at default configuration) now trusts the database.

Good Luck ;)

Grtz, Tom

Comment: The normal installation default location for the folder that you mention (for Access 2007) is "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office12\ACCWIZ". Your path is not a standard default path and most likely unique to your installation. Note that this folder does NOT have write access for a user without administrative rights, in case anyone is wondering whether this represents a security hole.