# Using SendKeys to Enable Content in an Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use `SendKeys` to `Enable Content` in an Excel Workbook. My procedure exists in workbook a. I am opening workbook b and would like to `Enable Content` in workbook b.

The part I am having trouble with is having the `SendKeys` work in unison. What I need the `SendKeys` to do is -

```
 Alt + F, I, N, {Enter}
```

Here are a couple of pieces of code I've tried -

**Attempt 1**

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
SendKeys "%f", True
SendKeys "i", True
SendKeys "n", True
SendKeys "~", True
```

**Result 1**

This results in an i and n being typed in workbook b

**Attempt 2**

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
SendKeys "%fin~", True
```

**Result 2**

Same as Result 1

**Attempt 3**

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
SendKeys "%f", True
SendKeys "i", True
SendKeys "n~", True
```

**Result 3**

Same as Result 1

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195580/how-to-get-rid-of-vba-security-warning

Comment: There are some features in Excel which cannot be programmatically enabled, for example, Trust Center settings to VBA Project Object Model, Macro Security, etc.  I believe "Enable Content" falls in the same category. TL;DR I am pretty sure you can't do this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was able to accomplish the same thing by adding the file location by going to Trust Center/Trust Center Settings/Trusted Locations/Add new location